# Input EOF character (Ctrl+D) in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, yacc, lex

I am  using yacc to parse my input. The parse method generated by yacc requires to input `EOF` character to mark the end of input. My code is working properly when build from shell. From the shell, I am able to terminate the input stream by `Ctrl+D` combination. But inside Eclipse `Ctrl+D` does not seem to work.

Could you help me figure out what could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a problem in eclipse, but seeing te be fixed in Eclipse 3.4. Make sure that you using a  later version.

Related bug report [HERE](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=34052)

Comment: I am using 3.5! Thanks for the information. Do you know of any workarounds.